# Cannot enable timeline module in drupal site

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

How to enable the simile timeline widget in drupal. I downloaded it from drupal site which is showing following problem.

Could any one give some suggestions or provide a path to solve this problem

Problem:

Provides a draggable and scrollable timeline view. Requires the views module and the libraries module and makes use of the cck and date module if available.
Requires: Views (missing), Ctools (missing), Date_api (missing), Libraries (missing)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to also download all of those modules that are listed as missing: 1) Views, 2) Ctools, 3) Date_api and 4) Libraries.

The module you're trying to download has these are pre-requisites, and you'll have to make sure those are in your modules/ directory before you can enable the timeline module.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is showing the timeline module is enabled. But do we need to code to see the timeline on drupal site?

Comment: I haven't used it, but the module has a documentation page here: http://drupal.org/node/561540.  Try to read through the first two pages of the documentation (installation and basic timeline view creation) to see if they help.